# Debian and jdk 1.7

Tags: debian, java, jdk

To run some applications on a server I require a version 1.7+

I tried to install JDK as shown in [link](http://openjdk.java.net/install/). However, it did could not retrieve the newest package of Java 8.
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`

which gave me

`Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk`

with

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

the installation went ahead but running

```
java -version
```

I get: `java version "1.6.0_36"`

The same package on ubuntu gave me a 1.7... as expected. Does this imply that the Debian repository does not have a proper jdk 1.7, or that I may have had an older installation of Java and need to further configure Java to run at the proper version?

I also took a look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58912/installing-jdk-7-on-debian) however it gave me no satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you have both JRE 6 and JRE 7 installed, and the older version is being preferred. There are two solutions to this:

1. Remove JRE 6, by running `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-*` (This will remove all parts of Java 6).
2. Run `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
sudo update-alternative --config java
```

Select `openjdk8` with enter number of them as default java.

```
sudo update-alternative --config javac
```

Select `openjdk8` with enter number of them as default javac.

```
sudo update-alternative --config javaws
```

Select `openjdk8` with enter number of them as default javaws.

Another way is get `jdk` (Java Developer's Kit). I think `jdk` is better than `openjdk` form site of oracle and follow me for installing them on Linux.

1. download `jdk`
2. extract them
3. move them in another folder `/usr/share/jvm/` or another directory
4. get permission to run bin software in bin directory in folder of your `jdk`
5. using these command for install `jdk`:

   ```
   sudo update-alternative --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/yourdirectoryjdk/bin/java" 1

   sudo update-alternative --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/yourdirectoryjdk/bin/javac" 1

   sudo update-alternative --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/yourdirectoryjdk/bin/javaws" 1

   sudo update-alternative --install "/usr/bin/jps" "jps" "/yourdirectoryjdk/bin/jps" 1
   ```
6. then you see your new `jdk` on list of alternative java program in Linux

   ```
   sudo update-alternative --config java
   ```

Comment: There is a package called 'java-package' which converts the downloaded jdk tarball from oracle into a proper Debian java package. Just run `apt install java-package`, then `make-jpkg <tarball>`, then install the generated .deb file. This will take care of the alternatives thing as well as dealing with other things useful for java in Debian (such as dependencies).